# Crash in UIKitCore: _UIAnalyticsGatherMultitouchAnalytics

Tags: ios

I only see this crash in Xcode > Window > Organizer > Crashes tab and not in Firebase Crashlytics.
It seems like it's only happening on iOS 13 so far and is one of the top 5 crashes in the app.

Also filed this in https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

[image]

Comment: Currently only seen in iPadOS 13.3 and 13.3.1 on iPad Pro models.

Comment: I am also suddenly getting this exact same crash under the same circumstances (ios = 13.3.1)

Answer (score 4):

I contacted Apple Developer support about this and got this answer:

---

In regards to what is happening in your crash logs, you definitely have a deallocated Zombie object that is being called causing this to crash.  Notice the crashing thread in each of logs ends with Objective-C sending a message resulting in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception type.

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x00000001b6338fb0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                        0x00000001b69eb558 probeGC + 124 (NSMapTable.m:721)
2   Foundation                        0x00000001b68fa2fc -[NSConcreteMapTable rehashAround:] + 208 (NSMapTable.m:1098)
3   Foundation                        0x00000001b68fa1fc -[NSConcreteMapTable removeObjectForKey:] + 252 (NSMapTable.m:1141)

The crash signature that you are seeing is consistent with other known crash signatures I am tracking right now:

2   Foundation                        0x00000001ad188d64 -[NSConcreteMapTable rehashAround:] + 204 (NSMapTable.m:1098)
3   Foundation                        0x00000001ad188c68 -[NSConcreteMapTable removeObjectForKey:] + 248 (NSMapTable.m:1141)
4   UIKitCore                         0x00000001b13d9484 _UIAnalyticsGatherMultitouchAnalytics + 632 (_UIMultitouchAnalytics.m:249)

I did some internal research on this issue and this is a bug right now in UIKit.  Other applications are experiencing the same thing so please make sure to list as much information as possible in the bug report.

---

However, I don’t have any other information than what I see through apples bug reports.

Just two things I noticed: 
This crash did so far occur under iOS 13.3.1 only. 
This crash does not seem to be completely random, several crashes have the same reporter ID, so they are coming from the same user. This might mean that some setting their devices makes the crash more likely.

Comment: Great info, thanks! That crash occurs to a small part of our iPad Pro users with iOS 13.3.1, but those that are affected experience it repeatedly.

Comment: Hi, 

I am experiencing exactly this bug (call stack footprint) from some users with iphone 8, X, Ipad (6th gen)  ios 13.3.1 .  crashes are completly random in my app (CutNPlace), never happened before, this version was very stable until the last three days